# Avoid running function within Unit Test (NUnit)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, nsubstitute

Say I have a class:

```
public class SomeClass {

   public Model _model;

   public SomeClass() {
     _model = new Model(); 
   }

   public void Foo() {
     _model.DoSomethingHeavy();
   }

}
```

And a Test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SomeClassTest {

  [Test]
  public void TestFooCalledSomethingHeavy() {
    SomeClass someClass = NSubstitute.Substitute.For<SomeClass>();  
    someClass.Foo();        
    someClass._model.Received().DoSomethingHeavy();
  }
}
```

I'm trying to test that someClass.Foo(); called _model.DoSomethingHeavy() but I don't actually want DoSomethingHeavy to run. How would I do that? Or is this the wrong approach?

Comment: are you familiar with Compiler Directives..? try that.. or put an entry in the .Config file for `IsTest` and check it at runtime based on the .Config key entry..

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What would the .Config file do? I'm not familiar with Compiler Directives no. The tests are being run via Unity's test runner if that helps.

Comment: do a google search on `#If TEST` do the following search in Google 
`C# stackoverflow using complier directives in Unity's test runner` and read up on what Compiler Directives are and how to use them.. there is also some for when running in Debug mode for example `#if Debug`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For overriding behavior of method with NSubstitute, the method need to be part of interface or virtual method.

First make sure that method `DoSomethingHeavy` marked as virtual or create interface(better -> gives more possibilities for testing) of `Model` class

```
public interface IModel
{
    void DoSomethingHeavy();
}
```

Implement interface in your `Model` class

```
public class Model : IModel
{
    public void DoSomethingHeavy()
    {
        // heavy staff
    }
}
```

Then, very important for testing -> remove responsibility for creating instance of `Model` outside of `SomeClass`

```
public class SomeClass 
{
    public Model _model { get; private set; }

    // Constructor will sure, that class get an instance of IModel
    public SomeClass(IModel model) 
    {
        _model = model; 
    }

    public void Foo() 
    {
        _model.DoSomethingHeavy();
    }
}
```

Now you can create fake of `IModel` and check that method `DoSomethingHeavy` executed without running real implementation.

Because `SomeClass` is class under the test, you don't need to mock it - you will test behavior of that class.

```
[Test]
public void TestFooCalledSomethingHeavy() 
{
    // Arrange
    IModel fakeModel = Substitute.For<IModel>();
    SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(fakeModel); 

    // Act 
    someClass.Foo();  

    // Assert      
    fakeModel.Received().DoSomethingHeavy();
}
```

Comment: excellent, allowing passing in the model was the key here, as I was able to pass in a mock. Works great.